# Tableau reading dates in wrong format

Tags: datetime, tableau-desktop

I have a csv file with time column  as "2022-02-08 00:00:27" (February 08th 2022) but when I import the csv file and set the date column as "date" type , "2022-02-08 00:00:27" gets intrepreted as (August 02nd 2022) .
How do I set the date format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your workbook locale from the file menu. Failing this you could build a new date field from the actual date, just reversing the components.

Steve